# I cannot debut a project in Code Blocks step by step

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm trying to debut my code step by step, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

The breakpoint is set but it seems to ignore it (doesn't appear the yellow arrow).

```
    Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\CodeBlocks\ArvoresBinarias2908\
Adding source dir: C:\CodeBlocks\ArvoresBinarias2908\
Adding file: C:\CodeBlocks\ArvoresBinarias2908\bin\Debug\ArvoresBinarias2908.exe
Changing directory to: C:/CodeBlocks/ArvoresBinarias2908/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Interactive Intelligence\ININ Trace Initialization;C:\Program Files (x86)\Interactive Intelligence\ICUserApps;C:\Program Files\Interactive Intelligence\ICUserApps
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args C:/CodeBlocks/ArvoresBinarias2908/bin/Debug/ArvoresBinarias2908.exe
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
Child process PID: 11644
[Inferior 1 (process 11644) exited normally]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Can someone please help me? I've already tried somethings that I found online, but no success:

- Tried with another code... no success.
- Moved the project to a folder with no spaces
- Checked true the "Produce debugging symbols" [-g]
- Disabled the "Enable all common compiler warning..."

I really don't understand that much about Debuggers, Compilers... I just want to debug thsi code to see the variable changes and other stuff.

Thanks!

ps. This is my first question here, so sorry if I didn't follow all the rules and standards that everybody here is used to.

Comment: Are you sure the place where you put the breakpoint is getting reached? Also, you should enable compiler warnings.

Comment: "*debut* is a nice typo ... ;-)

Comment: The point was being reached. I have no idea why, but restarting the PC fixed it. Thanks..

Comment: @alk I have no idea why I wrote "debut" twice.. My mistake, but t and g are closer on the keyboard, give me a discount hahaha